# When storing objects with over 15 attributes inside of dynamodb is it best to store as an object inside of value or spread them across the columns?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

So I decided to try something new when it comes to working with databases. I am following the one table design that was outlined by : [Rick video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k).

The one thing I am wondering is if I have an item to store inside the database specifically dynamodb will the cost be the same or different if I am spreading the attributes into their own columns or would it best to store an object (in this case store a list of map items) inside of one column instead of 15 columns? Also, is there a performance difference as well when reading across columns vs reading a larger object?

Ex. 
|userid|itemid|dataObject| vs |userid|itemid|dataObjectAttribute1|dataObjectAttribute2|...|dataObjectAttribute15

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Save separate attributes.

Reason for saved separate attributes:

- Flexible index
- Saving item size. You can check it at (https://zaccharles.github.io/dynamodb-calculator/)
- Limit Attributes return

Reason for saved embed attributes as Map:

- Quick and simple.
- You don't need any indexes on those attributes, just save as raw data and always return all
- You need something as data unstructrure/dynamic, or grouping attributes